# TypeScript Utility Types use case

Tags: typescript, typescript-utility

```
type Product = {
  name: string;
  price: number;
}

// Utility Type A
type Keys<T> = keyof T & string;

// Utility Type A without "& string"
type Keys<T> = keyof T & string;

type KeysOfProduct = Keys<Product>
```

Given the above condition, what are the differences when we use Utility Type A or Utility Type A without "& string"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `& string` is used to eliminate any keys of the object which are not strings. In other words, it gets rid of numbers and symbols. Your `Product` type doesn't have any of these, but different objects might.

For example:

```
const foo = Symbol();

type Product = {
  name: string;
  price: number;
  [3]: boolean;
  [foo]: string;
}

type KeysWithoutString<T> = keyof T;
type KeysWithString<T> = keyof T & string

const example1: KeysWithoutString<Product> = 'name';
const example2: KeysWithoutString<Product> = 'price';
const example3: KeysWithoutString<Product> = 'error'; // Error (not a key)
const example4: KeysWithoutString<Product> = 3; // Allow
const example5: KeysWithoutString<Product> = foo; // Allowed

const example6: KeysWithString<Product> = 'name';
const example7: KeysWithString<Product> = 'price';
const example8: KeysWithString<Product> = 'error'; // Error (not a key)
const example9: KeysWithString<Product> = 3; // Error (a key, but not a string)
const example10: KeysWithString<Product> = foo; // Error (a key, but not a string)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=16&pln=5&pc=17#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDKBPAtgIxAGwAoBKAbgFgAoKqDABwFMYAFAJxABMBXYWVAbyowYYAIZYGALhjRWASzABzCpWF15wKSK64GrFcIDaAZgC60vAQaiwBmIYQhzMqPKUqAvlRr0mAaQYMCAB1OSgACzRXBUUAHgAVAD4UGABrQJA4GHiYADIXN0VvSlpGGACg0IiQLigowoTk1HSMTOyVKlBIWAYAD3E6fAYARmkKkLDwmrropVi2Th4oJpgAcjEJVZUu6Bg+gaGAJjHAiera+pj59m5eFdX1OU0tzvBd-axBhmMTysnpy5zBa3ZYpVZ6disF6UHY9fqfIYAFl+ZymF1mcWBSxWxm2bzhBwYAFYUVU0TMGli7ilHB0Yfi9vCvgA2UmTQGYm7YsEbBjQ2GMwkAdjZEQ510W1NQDw0fLx3UFCIYAA5RZEMRKQfcISAofL3kyhgBONXiqmg1C414Kj5fYYABlNGvNK1pQA)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. The `& string` in this case results in an effectual no-op. Since the *keys* of `Product` are string literals (`name`, `price`), intersecting the general `string` type with them just results in a type representing the string literals `name` and `price` still.

If you wanted to allow loose strings as well as the strongly typed ones you would do `keyof T | string` instead.